# Causes of Error 35602: Key is not unique in collection

Tags: windows-10, runtime-error

When attempting to simulate or compile a PLD file on [WinCupl](https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/programmable-logic/spld-cpld/tools/software/wincupl), I get the error:

> Error '35602':
>
> Key is not unique in collection.

after which the program crashes and closes.

What is the meaning of an error like this? A quick search brings up many questions (e.g., [this](https://community.ivanti.com/docs/DOC-63696), [this](http://kb.pastel.co.za/assets/Error%2035602%20Key%20not%20unique%20in%20collection.pdf), or [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?710931-RESOLVED-Access-XP-35602-Key-is-not-unique-in-collection)), but these all yield application-specific solutions. My scenario is also application-specific, but WinCupl is an old program and I can't find similar support online.

Some of the answers to those questions say something along the lines of: "This problem is caused by a key in a table of the database that is not unique." Can someone give some insight on what this means, and/or possible solutions to look into?

---

<sub>Note: I was thinking about posting on [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but this program doesn't seem to be commonly asked about on that site and I thought I might get a better understanding of the error here. If you think a different Stack Exchange site is better suited for this question, please flag/comment.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same same problem and traced it back to a point where the tree in the project window is populated .  I was able to work around it unticking Project under View on the Menu before compiling.  Not sure if this will work for you but I spent hours looking for a solution to this so figured I'd share my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that some time has passed since the question was created, but I hope this will help someone else.
I have the same error, but it occurred when I just opened the project. And so, as I discovered, the reason was the same file name (I copied the project file before some test changes to **same-filename.pld.store**). For some reason I had to close the project and WinCUPL, and when I tried to open it again, I got this error. The first thing that helped was to move the project file to another location. It opened normally. And then I moved the copy file to another location, and returned the project file back. And it opened normally again. Returning a copy to the old location and the project returns an error again.